# Document Library Link to Item

Tags: document-library

does anybody know a simple way to make the listview of a document library link to an item (dispform not editform) instead of opening the document on click?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, there's no simple way.

I solved the problem using an event receiver generating a column that includes the information to open the popup for the dispform.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a link to display form by creating new text column on a list and setting following properties on it from code or PowerShell: *LinkToItem* and *LinkToItemAllowed*. I don't think those options are available anywhere in GUI in SharePoint 2013.

Example:

```
 SPField field = spList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldInternalName);
 field.LinkToItemAllowed = SPField.ListItemMenuState.Required;
 field.LinkToItem = true;
 field.Update();
```

Doing it this way you don't need Event Receiver.

It seems however that the link generated this way doesn't care about list's settings on whether to open forms in a popup or a page (and always just generates link to a page).

Also, there'sa similar question now: [sp2013: Column with link to the displayform like on the title column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94968/sp2013-column-with-link-to-the-displayform-like-on-the-title-column)

I know this is an old question, but with SharePoint 2013 and Online people might still stumble upon similar problem :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option (in 2013) where you can use CSR.

In below js code what I have done is, given the display form link to the `Title` column of a document library.

```
RegisterModuleInit('/SiteAssets/Titlelink.js', updateTitle);
updateTitle();

function updateTitle() {
    var priorityFiledContext  = {};
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};    
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Title": {
            "View": priorityFiledTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);
}

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {       
    var url = String.format('{0}&amp;ID={1}', ctx.displayFormUrl, ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
    var ret =   "<a href='" + url + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</a>";
    return ret; 
}
```

Hope this also helps.