# sp2013: Column with link to the displayform like on the title column?

Tags: column, display-form, edit-form

I'm using SharePoint 2013. I have a custom list and a custom Content Type.

I have edited the view and deactivated the title column because I don't use it. I now miss a column with a link to the DispForm.aspx like in the title column did.

How can I add a column in my view with a link to the DispForm.aspx?

I'm already using the column "Edit (link to edit item)". But this is going to the EditForm.aspx. I don't want the edit form but would like the displayform.

This is the [link](http://mycompany.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B3DC46D7D-4669-4005-A521-4C295CD48B29%7D&ID=2&ContentTypeID=0x0100BA09E7695455FC4B8D3716A128EF73B3007B72F1DF8FAFDE4D9C9550B4482D23C0) on the column "Title (linked to item with edit menu)":

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer my self. I would like to share it with you:)

Open the AllItems.aspx page for the specific list.
Search for the  tag
List item LinkToItem="TRUE" to whichever column you want the link:

```
< ViewFields>
< FieldRef Name=”Attachments”/>
< FieldRef Name=”LinkTitle”/>
< FieldRef Name=”linkThisColumn” LinkToItem=”TRUE”/>
< FieldRef Name=”data_x0020_column”/>
< FieldRef Name=”Another_x0020_column”/>
< /ViewFields>
```

You can use LinkToItem, LinkToItemAllowed and ListItemMenu properties of SPField. If you want field to show link to item’s display form you need to set LinkToItem property to true and LinkToItemAllowed property to Allowed. If you want to add context menu to field you need to set ListItemMenu to true.

Answer (score 0):

In fact to get your drop down menu to be near your column you must do

`< ViewFields>
    < FieldRef Name=”Attachments”/>
    < FieldRef Name=”LinkTitle”/>
    < FieldRef Name=”linkThisColumn” ListItemMenu="TRUE" linkToItem="TRUE"/>
    < FieldRef Name=”data_x0020_column”/>
    < FieldRef Name=”Another_x0020_column”/>
    < /ViewFields>`

This saves my day ;)